# Testing with Mockito

Tags: spring, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to test some services with Mockito but I have problems when the main class that I test and where I inject Mocks calls to super.
I run the project with spring and these are the steps I follow to get the error.

Here is where I create the test

```java
public class UrlShortenerTests {

 private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @Mock
 private ShortURLRepository shortURLRepository;

 @Mock
 private ClickRepository clickRespository;

 @InjectMocks
 private UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs urlShortenerWL;


 @Before
 public void setup() {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
     this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(urlShortenerWL).build();
 }

 @Test
 public void thatShortenerCreatesARedirectIfTheURLisOK() throws Exception {
     mockMvc.perform(post("/link")
             .param("url", "http://www.google.com"))
             .andDo(print())
             .andExpect(status().isCreated())
             .andExpect(jsonPath("$.target", is("http://example.com/")));
 }
}
```

Here is the class UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs with the method shortener, which is the one I want to test with the previous POST call

```java
@RestController
public class UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs extends UrlShortenerController {

@Autowired
private ClickRepository clickRepository;
@Autowired
private ShortURLRepository SURLR;

public ResponseEntity<ShortURL> shortener(@RequestParam("url") String url,
        @RequestParam(value = "sponsor", required = false) String sponsor,
        @RequestParam(value = "brand", required = false) String brand,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    ResponseEntity<ShortURL> su = super.shortener(url, sponsor, brand,
            request);
    return su;
}
```

And this is the super class

```java
@RestController
public class UrlShortenerController {

@Autowired
protected ShortURLRepository shortURLRepository;

@Autowired
protected ClickRepository clickRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/link", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<ShortURL> shortener(@RequestParam("url") String url,
        @RequestParam(value = "sponsor", required = false) String sponsor,
        @RequestParam(value = "brand", required = false) String brand,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    ShortURL su = createAndSaveIfValid(url, sponsor, brand, UUID
            .randomUUID().toString(), extractIP(request));
    if (su != null) {
        HttpHeaders h = new HttpHeaders();
        h.setLocation(su.getUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(su, h, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}

protected ShortURL createAndSaveIfValid(String url, String sponsor,
        String brand, String owner, String ip) {
    UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(new String[] { "http",
            "https" });
    if (urlValidator.isValid(url)) {
        String id = Hashing.murmur3_32()
                .hashString(url, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString();
        ShortURL su = new ShortURL(id, url,
                linkTo(
                        methodOn(UrlShortenerController.class).redirectTo(
                                id, null)).toUri(), sponsor, new Date(
                        System.currentTimeMillis()), owner,
                HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT.value(), true, ip, null);
        return shortURLRepository.save(su);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, when I call to shortURLRepository.save(su) in the second method (createAndSaveIfValid), it never enters in the method save, so it returns me null instead of the object I want.

The code of the implementation of ShortURLRepository and the method save is:

```java
@Repository
public class ShortURLRepositoryImpl implements ShortURLRepository {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(ShortURLRepositoryImpl.class);
@Override
public ShortURL save(ShortURL su) {
    try {
        jdbc.update("INSERT INTO shorturl VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                su.getHash(), su.getTarget(), su.getSponsor(),
                su.getCreated(), su.getOwner(), su.getMode(), su.getSafe(),
                su.getIP(), su.getCountry());
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        log.debug("When insert for key " + su.getHash(), e);
        return su;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("When insert", e);
        return null;
    }
    return su;
}
```

I think that the problem is that the object ShortURLRepository created in the test class is not initialized on the super class (UrlShortenerController) or something similar.

Is it possible?
Can anybody help me?

The full code is in: https://github.com/alberto-648702/UrlShortener2014

The class UrlShortenerTests is in:

```
bangladeshGreen/src/test/java/urlshortener2014/bangladeshgreen
```

The class UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs is in:

```
bangladeshGreen/src/main/java/urlshortener2014/bangladeshgreen/web
```

The class UrlShortenerController is in:

```
common/src/main/java/urlshortener2014/common/web
```

The class ShortURLRepositoryImpl is in:

```
common/src/main/java/urlshortener2014/common/repository
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error. This is the expected behaviour. `@Mock` creates a mock. `@InjectMocks` creates an instance of the class and injects the mocks that are created with the `@Mock`. A mock is not a real object with known values and methods. It is an object that has the same interface as the declared type but you control its behaviour. By default the mocked object methods do nothing (e.g. return `null`). Therefore if `ShortURLRepository` is mocked and injected in `UrlShortenerControllerWithLogs` calling `save` in the injected `ShortURLRepository` does not call the real code as you expected, it does nothing. If you want to mock the behaviour of `save`, add the following code in your `setup`:

```
when(shortURLRepository.save(org.mockito.Matchers.any(ShortURL.class))).
    then(new Answer<ShortURL>() {
        @Override
        public ShortURL answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            ShortURL su = (ShortURL) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            // Do something with su if needed
            return su;
    }
});
```